# Case Comment External Creator

Tags: email, notification

We're using the Self Service Portal for Case Management, I have some emails going out for the support team on new cases created and new case comments. One modification I was requested to do is display the case comment creator name on the email (either if it's an internal user or a SSP user). 
The current "Case Comment. Created by" shows only internal users. 
Is there any way to show the SSP Users name on this kind of email?

Thanks!

Itay

Comment: Who is listed in the Case Comment Created By field when comments are added on the SSP?